# Covariance of the estimators and the multivariate Cramer-Rao inequality

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

From the multivariate version of the Cramer-Rao inequality I learned that $Var(\hat{\theta_i})\geq (I(\vec{\theta})^{-1})_{ii}$, where $I(\vec{\theta})$ is the Fisher Information matrix. Now, I am wondering whether I can generalize this inequality to the covariance of $\hat{\theta_i}$ and $\hat{\theta_j}$,

i.e.,  $Cov(\hat{\theta_i},\hat{\theta_j})\geq (I(\vec{\theta})^{-1})_{ij}$ ?

I'm asking this because a book I'm reading told me if the estimators are efficient I should expect $Cov(\hat{\theta_i},\hat{\theta_j})=(I(\vec{\theta})^{-1})_{ij}$. However, a proof was not given in that book and I can neither prove this on my own nor find a proof elsewhere.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: For normal data estimators $\bar X$ for $\mu$ and $S^2$ for $\sigma^2$ are independent, but beware that estimators are not always independent.

Comment: Agree. But, any hints for the proof of $Cov(\hat{\theta_i},\hat{\theta_j})\geq (I(\vec{\theta})^{-1})_{ij}$ ?

Comment: Sorry, only tangential musings occur.